# How to Branch and keep the branch history with TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I need to create a branch in TFS and copy the code and the history from the parent branch.

I am using TFS 2013 with Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to easily do this ?

Comment: Is it a branch that you are trying to create or a new project line from the main one? If you create a branch it should have all the history preserved.
For branching strategy check the doc https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: @Angshuman I'm looking to create a new branch. After I branch when I view the History of the new branch all that I see is the initial check-in of that branch. There is no option to roll back to a previous changeset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branching is a technique for creating a parallel set of versions of your files. So the branch will have the same codebase as parent branch.

Regarding the history, the file will keep the history under the branch change, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: What I'm seeing is that the new branch doesn't have the history of the change sets, so I can't roll back to an old change set.

Comment: Check a single file, not folder.

Comment: I have tried that and I can see the file history. Unfortunately the option to rollback is not available. It looks like I will have to undo the changes manulay