# How to track the branched history through tf command?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I know this can be achieved through IDE from this link [How to Branch and keep the branch history with TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310446/how-to-branch-and-keep-the-branch-history-with-tfs-2013)

However,  I want to achieve this by tf command. I have tried tf history, not the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use `tf branchs` command instead of `tf history` command which displays the history of a branch for a specified file or folder.

```
tf branches itemspec [/version:versionspec] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [/login:username,[password]]
```

More detail info, please refer to the link from MSDN: [Branches Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcbx5yce.aspx)